# LNK2022 when converting VS2010 project from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, clr

I am converting a VS2010 project from 32-bit to 64-bit.  Compiles fine, but when it attempts to link, I get the following errors:

```
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x040000bc).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x020000bc).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x040000c0).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x020000c0).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x040000c1).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x020000c1).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x040000c9).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x020000c6).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x040000ca).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x020000c7).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x040000de).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x020000d3).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000036).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x02000037).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000037).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000038).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000038).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x02000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x0200003b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003c).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x0200003c).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000044).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(dbgdel.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x0200003d).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000034).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x02000035).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000035).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000036).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000036).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x02000037).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x02000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x0200003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000042).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(delete2.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x0200003b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000033).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x02000034).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000035).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000036).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000036).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x02000037).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x02000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x0200003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000042).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x0200003b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000049).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x0200005e).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400004f).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000065).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000050).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x02000066).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000067).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x02000070).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000068).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x02000071).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000083).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xmutex.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x02000077).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000033).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x02000034).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x0200003b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x0200003c).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000040).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x02000040).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000041).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x02000041).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400004b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x02000044).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000035).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x02000036).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x0200003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x0200003b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003f).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x02000040).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000040).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x02000041).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400004c).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x02000046).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000034).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x02000035).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000038).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HWND__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000039).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HWND__): (0x0200003a).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagRECT; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003e).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagRECT): (0x0200003f).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: HDC__; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400003f).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (HDC__): (0x02000040).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; fields: <alignment member>): (0x0400004b).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): (0x02000045).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_toupper.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: _GUID; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000034).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_toupper.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (_GUID): (0x02000035).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_toupper.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: tagMSG; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000037).
 1>MSVCURTD.lib(_toupper.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Differing number of fields in duplicated types (tagMSG): (0x02000038).
 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors
```

This project is primarily a Windows Forms GUI that is interfacing to a .dll.  The .dll, which is a separate VS2010 project has compiled and linked fine.

I have been beating my head against the wall for 2 days on the problem and am at a loss of where to look next.

Please let me know of any other details that may be useful.

Comment: Still linking with some library (static or dynamic) being 32-bit instead of 64-bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LNK2022 metadata operation: Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990095/lnk2022-metadata-operation-inconsistent-layout-information-in-duplicated-types)

Comment: Alan, Thanks that was a good link.  One of the suggestions in that link recommended changing the Struct Member Alignment to 16 bytes.  Doing so allowed it to link properly... now I just have to figure out how/if that affects my code.

Answer (score 0):

Change Struct Member Alignment to "bytes" in Project settings-> configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code generation.

This is because 4 byte struct alignment is not supported in 64 bit. It needs to be at least 8 bytes (8x8 =64). You can change this option in settings to get through the compilation errors. it does not mean your program will be working.

[image]